# as3 getting object coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Hello everyone so i have a piece of code witch creates some circles, and after i move them with another function i want to get their center coordinates so i can draw lines from center to center of circles, but i don`t have any idea how to do it ... if you can suggest me 1 , here is the code witch creates the circle :

```
function new_sond(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (i<9)
    {
    i++;
    q=i;
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();  
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0x0099FF, 1);
    btn.graphics.drawCircle(400, 300, 15);
    btn.graphics.endFill();
    var s:String = String(q);
    btn.name=s; 
    var textField = new TextField();
    textField.mouseEnabled=false;
    textField.text = i;
    textField.width = 10; 
    textField.height = 17;
    textField.x = 395; // center it horizontally
    textField.y = 292; // center it vertically
    btn.addChild(textField);
    this.addChild(btn);
    }
}
```

the code with is mooving them is :

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownH);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpH);

function mouseDownH(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var object = evt.target;
    object.startDrag();
}

function mouseUpH(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var obj = evt.target;
        obj.stopDrag();
}
```

And the code where i draw the lines between them :

```
function click1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click1);
    var i:int;
    i=1;
    if (e.target.name!=null){
    trace(e.target.name);
    sx=mouseX;
    sy=mouseY;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click2);
    }
}

function click2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);
    fx=mouseX;
    fy=mouseY;
    var i:int;
    i=2;
    trace(e.target.name);
    var  line:Shape = new Shape();
    line.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x0066FF,1);
    line.graphics.moveTo(sx,sy);
    line.graphics.lineTo(fx,fy);
    this.addChild(line);
    var inputField:TextField = new TextField();
    inputField.border = true;
    inputField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    str=inputField.text;
    trace(str);
    inputField.width = 23;
    inputField.height = 18;
    inputField.x = (sx+fx)/2;
    inputField.y = (sy+fy)/2;
    addChild(inputField);
}
```

The thing is i want to draw the line from center to center, but i get the mouseX and mouseY coordinates to draw, because i don`t know how to take the center coordinates of an object.... what i get is : http://gyazo.com/6003630d549209ec5e16ccfffe0ee689
But i want the lines to be drawn from center, if someone has any suggestions please help

Sorry for the long post, i just don`t know where i need to put the piece with will center them so i wanted to give the hole code where it can be placed.... I will appreciate very much any idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you drew the circle at 0,0 and moved the btn object .x and .y to 400,300 like this:

```
btn.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,15);
btn.x = 400;
btn.y = 300;
```

Then as you drag btn around the screen, `btn.x` , `btn.x` (or in the click handler, `e.target.x` and `e.target.y`) would always be the center of the circle.

Alternately, if you can't or don't want to do it that way, you can get the bounds of btn (with respect to `this` coordinate system, since that's where `line` is being drawn), and since it's a circle, then center of the bounds will be the center of the circle:

```
var btn:Sprite = e.target;
var bounds:Rectangle = btn.getBounds(this);
var center_x:Number = bounds.x + bounds.width/2;
var center_y:Number = bounds.y + bounds.height/2;
```